# Can't run video file with MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, xcode4, mpmovieplayercontroller

Here is my code

```
-(IBAction)playvideo:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"Get in");
    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video3" ofType:@"MOV"];
MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
    NSLog(@"movie path %@",moviePath);
    NSLog(@"movie %@",movie);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieViewFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:movie];
    movie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    movie.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:movie.view];
    [movie setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [movie play];
}
```

and Here is my log

> 2012-03-16 16:54:39.080 TestVideofile[510:11f03] Get in 2012-03-16
>   16:54:39.303 TestVideofile[510:11f03] movie path
>   /Users/crazyoxy/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.1/Applications/7F1425B8-6DB0-4A09-AC8F-3BCDBF19ED95/TestVideofile.app/video3.MOV
>   2012-03-16 16:54:39.304 TestVideofile[510:11f03] movie <
>   MPMoviePlayerController: 0x7a8ea30 >

After I click button that link with this IBAction, it turns to black page but didn't show video or even any audio.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried this on an actual device rather than the simulator? (I can see you're running from the I'm your log).

Comment: Nope not yet. I have some problem with my provision so I cant run with my iPad :( Oh and video3.MOV is movie that I recorded by my iPhone4 so I think video file wont have any error too.

Comment: Umm I ran with another iPad but it still show black page. :(

Comment: dude try `NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video3.MOV" ofType:nil];` actually i ran into the same problem long ago, and the type change has fixed my issue , i think. just try and let me know

Comment: I just change my code and now it's WORKKK but not make sense. I move MPMoviePlayerController *movie to .h file. And property and synthesize it.and it work - - Could you tell me why it's work ? I don't get it.By the way very thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using ARC and the player gets released if no further references exist.

Adding it as a property to your ViewController instance keeps the instance alive as long as the ViewController is.

Comment: Thanks u very much... It costs me too much time. :D